# show page loading icon while loading table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have table in html file as `<table id="table" class="table table-striped">`
And I call `getTableData` function and dynamically update table using jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            getTable();
           $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
          ...
    });
```

I am using ajaxStop to run next functions after table is rendered.

```
    function getTable(){
    $.get("api/table", function(data){
    setTable(data);
    }
}
```

where `setTable` renders table. How can I show loading icon while table data is fetched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can send a `success` callback on `$.get()` (so when data are received) and handle your loading with a CSS class:

```
 function getTable(){
     // Before call your server Add loading style
     $('#table').addClass('is-loading')
     $.get("api/table", function(data){
          // Just after receiving data Remove loading style
          $('#table').removeClass('is-loading')
          setTable(data);
     }
 }
```